# discord.py getting custome server username

Tags: python, discord.py

I started programming my discord bot, it's a default roulette bot, but I asked myself how I could get the server-wide username?

`message.author` returns the real username, but I want the Server-Username

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [`Member.nick`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.nick), or in your case `message.author.nick`